# Wordpress. Отправка информации в таблицу MSSQL

Tags: wordpress, sql-server

Сайт на Wordpress, на нем есть форма анкетирования. Возможна ли отправка данных из формы в таблицу MSSQL на внешнем ресурсе?

Comment: Если внешний ресурс позволяет удалённый доступ к базе, то почему нет?

Comment: привяжитесь к хуку отправки формы и там выполните запрос на mssql

Comment: Для начала стоит выяснить - как на внешнем ресурсе нужно писать в базу - напрямую SQLем или через АПИ. А так же какие возможности доступа (куда) имеются